# Assembler program counts sum incorrectly

Tags: assembly, nasm

I'm trying to find the sum of the unsigned elements in the array and if in stash bit 1, then byte invert. Test data: 126 (01111110) 8 times and 254 (11111110) will be 1 after invert and answer should be 126*8+1=1135. but my answer is 3389849841. warning: move to read-only section ".text"
warning: DT_TEXTREL is created in PIE

```
; nasm -felf32 test.asm && gcc -m32 test.o && ./a.out
section .data
        msg db 'Sum: %u', 10, 0
        sum_len equ $-msg

        nextline db 10

        arr db 0, 254, 126, 126, 126, 126, 126, 126, 126, 126
        arr_len equ 10

%macro print 2
        mov eax, 4
        mov ebx, 1
        mov ecx, %1
        mov edx, %2
        int 80h
%endmacro

section .text
        global main
        extern printf

main:

        mov esi, arr
        mov ecx, arr_len

        xor ebx, ebx

loop:
        mov al, byte[esi]
        test al, 10000000b
        jz summary

        not al

summary:
        add bl, al

        add esi, 1
        dec ecx
        jnz loop

        push bx
        push msg
        call printf

exit:
        mov eax, 01
        mov ebx, 0
        int 80h
```

UPD

```
section .data
        msg db 'Sum: %u', 10, 0
        sum_len equ $-msg

        nextline db 10

        arr dd 0, 254, 126, 126, 126, 126, 126, 126, 126, 126
        arr_len equ 10

%macro print 2
        mov eax, 4
        mov ebx, 1
        mov ecx, %1
        mov edx, %2
        int 80h
%endmacro

section .text
        global main
        extern printf

main:

        mov esi, arr
        mov ecx, arr_len

        xor ebx, ebx

loop:
        mov eax, dword[esi]
        test eax, 10000000b
        jz summary

        not al

summary:
        add ebx, eax

        add esi, 4
        dec ecx
        jnz loop

        push ebx
        push msg
        call printf

exit:
        mov eax, 01
        mov ebx, 0
        int 80h
```

Comment: You defined `arr db ... ` which means 8-bit data, but use `bt word[esi], 15` and `add esi, 2` which are for 16-bit data. So the first 5 tests will be treating *pairs* of 8-bit values, and the next 5 tests will be testing undefined data (beyond the end of the defined array). As you are testign bit 15, it looks as though you intended to use `dw` not `db`, however, none of those values listed have either bit 7 or bit 15 set.

Comment: i change to add esi, 1 and bt word[esi], 7 then sum is 291438.
but if i change only arr db to arr dw then sum is 1134

Comment: That's 126 * 9 as expected. Bit 7 or 15 is not set in any of the data, so there is never any inversion. I overlooked that you are reading into `ax` a 16-bit register. The narrative mentions bit 1. And remember that `add ebx, eax` adds 32-bit value and the upper part of eax has not be cleared.

Comment: I forgot that the numbering is from 0, thanks for help

Comment: I made adjustments, but still somewhere I make mistakes

Comment: `push bx` - that's wrong, printf will be looking for a 32-bit stack arg.  (Even if you used `%hu` for an unsigned short, you should still `push ebx` - stack args always take up at least 1 full register-width slot of stack memory).  `3389849841 & 65535` is `241`, so without the high garbage, that's the BX value you pushed.

Comment: Yes, calls to a variadic function like `printf()` should promote all integers smaller than `int` to `int` (and promote `float` to `double`).

Comment: ok, i start work with 32 bit values but i see that 254 after invert is 246 and i've got segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./a.out

Comment: Your "update" doesn't show output.  if you just fixed the BX / EBX bug, I'd suggest just updating the original code block and actual output, not having 2 versions.  Or if you changed more than that, say so and show actual output.  Also, build with `-no-pie` so GCC / ld won't warn you about using absolute addresses in the .text section.

Comment: Also, what do you see when you single-step through this with a debugger?  (for example, GDB.  See GDB tips at the bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info)

Comment: ok, i paste output before checking the loop and i see 1009 it's correct answer but it repeats itself endlessly and a segmentation fault occurs (126*8+1=1009) and if the output is put after the check, then 127 is shown but everything is correctly completed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you all for your help here is a working program

```
; nasm -felf32 test.asm && gcc -m32 -no-pie test.o && ./a.out
section .data
        msg db 'Sum: %u', 10, 0
        sum_len equ $-msg

        nextline db 10

        arr dd 0, 254, 126, 126, 126, 126, 126, 126, 126, 126
        arr_len equ 10

%macro print 2
        mov eax, 4
        mov ebx, 1
        mov ecx, %1
        mov edx, %2
        int 80h
%endmacro

section .text
        global main
        extern printf

main:

        mov esi, arr
        mov ecx, arr_len

        xor ebx, ebx

loop:
        mov eax, dword[esi]
        test eax, 10000000b
        jz summary

        not al

summary:
        add ebx, eax

        add esi, 4
        dec ecx
        cmp ecx, 0
        jne loop

        push ebx
        push msg
        call printf

exit:
        mov eax, 01
        mov ebx, 0
        int 80h
```

Comment: What did you change / fix?  If you don't point that out, future readers are going to have a hard time learning anything from this, or finding it as a duplicate for some other program with the same bug.

Comment: most likely the version that I indicated in the question (second) is correct, but I did not notice it (error in theoretical calculations)